# Is it possible to pass several rows of data into a MySQL subquery instead of using a temporary table?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'd like to know if it's possible to pass rows of data directly into a select subquery, rather than setting up a temporary table and joining on that.

My actual use case is trying to prevent thousands of individual queries, and for architectural reasons adding a temporary table would be a pain (but not impossible, so it's where I may have to go.)

An simplified example of my issue is :

I have a table giving the number plate of the cars in a car park, with each row containing section (a letter), space (a number), and reg_plate (a tinytext).

My boss gives me a list of 3 places and wants the reg number of the car in each (or null if empty).

Now I can do this by creating a temporary table containing the section/space sequence I'm interested in, and then join my carpark table against that to give me each of the rows.

I'm wondering is there a syntax where I could do this in a select, perhaps with a subselect something like this - obviously invalid, but hopefully it shows what I'm getting at:

```
SELECT targets.section, targets.space, cp.reg_plate
FROM carpark cp 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT field1 AS section, field2 AS space
    FROM (
       ('a', 7), ('c', 14), ('c', 23)
    )  
) targets ON (cp.section = targets.section AND cp.space = targets.space)
```

Any ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION`:

```
SELECT targets.section, targets.space, cp.reg_plate
FROM carpark cp 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'a' as section, 7 AS space
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 14
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 23
) targets ON cp.section = targets.section AND cp.space = targets.space
```

Answer (score 0):

A followup;
I realised I was hoping to find something analagous to the VALUES used in an insert statement.
It turns out this is available in MySQL 8+, and VALUES is available as a table constructor:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

```
SELECT targets.section, targets.space, cp.reg_plate
FROM carpark cp 
LEFT JOIN (
    VALUES
       ROW ('a', 7), ROW('c', 14), ROW('c', 23)
    )  
) targets ON (cp.section = targets.column_0 AND cp.space = targets.column_1)
```

Not available in earlier MySQL (so the UNION method is OK) but great in 8+.